# Google Custom Search API, Howto return country specific results only

Tags: google-search-api

I am making some PHP code which takes a given search phrase and url and searches through the google search results until it finds the url (only first 100 results). My problem is, this is only working for the US. I have tried adding the "&cr=" option, but it still on returns US results.

The full URL I am using for the request is:

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_KEY&cx=CX_VALUE&q=KEYWORD&cr=COUNTRY&alt=JSON

Does anyone have any experience with this? I want to be able to see UK results. Tried inserting &cr=countryUK , but still only does US results.

Thanks :)

Regards,
Stian

Comment: Does anyone know another forum where I could ask this, and possibly get an answer?

Comment: have you been able to solve this issue?

Comment: Nope, I haven't resolved it yet.. The google API doesn't seem to support any country parameters in the REST request.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `gl=<country code>` param to limit it to your country of choice (so gl=gb for the uk).

More info here:

http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com/2009/10/web-search-in-your-country.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/10321396/936284: hl=user interface language, gl=geolocation (tld of google), lr=results of a specfic language